# C++ validating date without using class

Tags: c++, validation, date

Hi I am hoping someone can help me out with what I am doing wrong.  This is homework I will point out but was in need of someone to tell me what a moron I am because I am not seeing what it is that I am doing wrong.

I am supposed to let the user enter a month, day, and year to determine if it is a magic date.  That part I had already done for another project. I am supposed to go back and validate the date using a function named isDateValid. I'm pretty sure I am missing something obvious and could use anyones help on the subject.  Thanks!

The problem is when I run it I am always getting that it is an invalid date!

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 bool leapYear(int);
 bool isDateValid(int, int, int);

 int main()
 {
 int month, day, year;

 cout << "Is the date you are thinking of a magic one? Let's see...\n";
 cout << "What is the month in numeric form only? "; cin >> month;
 cout << "What is the day of the month? "; cin >> day;
 cout << "What is the four digit year? "; cin >> year;

 if (isDateValid(month, day, year) == false)
 {
 cout << "The date you entered, "<< month << "/" << day << "/" << 
 year << " is NOT a VALID Date.\n";
 cout << "If you think I am wrong, please feel free to run me again";
 }

 else   if (month * day == year % 100) // if true then do this
 {
 cout << "The date you entered, " << 
 month << "/" << day << "/" << year << " is a magic date!!\n"; 
 }
 else // if false then do this
 {
 cout << "The date you entered, " << month << "/" << day << "/" <<
 year << " is NOT a magic date!!\n";
 }

                                                            //Program ID
 cout <<"\n" << "L5P1LB.cpp\n" << "11-26-12\n" << endl;
 system ("pause");
 return 0;
 }//end main

 // isDateValid function to validate date entered
 bool isDateValid(int month, int day, int year)
 {
 bool validation = true;
 if(!(year >= 1600 && year <=2100))
     validation = false;    
 if(leapYear(year))
 {
     if ((month == 2) && (day > 29))
         validation = false;
     }
 else if(!leapYear(year))
 {
      if ((month == 2) && (day > 28))
          validation = false;
          }    
 if((month < 1 && month > 12) || (day < 1))
     validation = false;
 if((month == 1) || (month ==3) || (month == 5) || (month == 7) ||
     (month == 8) || (month == 10) || (month == 12) && (day > 31))
     validation = false;
 else if (((month == 4) || (month == 6) || (month == 9) || (month == 11)) && 
      (day > 30))
      validation = false;
 else
      validation == true;
 return validation;
 }
 // leapYear function to determine if the year is a leap year for validation
 bool leapYear(int year)
 {
 return(year % 100 != 0 && year % 4 == 0) || (year % 400 == 0);
 } // end leapYear
```

EDIT

Okay now my problem is that I am not getting that it is NOT A valid date when it is.  Its skipping the validation all together and just running the "magic date" part of it!

Here's the rewrite plus my full code hopefully indented here properly as it is in Bloodshed.

```
Description: This program determines if when the user enters a month, 
day, and four digit year which will then be stripped down to its
two digit year and determined to be a magic date if the day entered 
multiplied by the month entered equals the years two digit format.
Design:
    begin main
        input data
            Ask user for a month in number form
            Ask user for a day of the month
            Ask user for four digit month
        Validate
            begin isDateValid
                if year is between 1600 and 2100, inclusive then return 
                    true
                if month is between 1 and 12, inclusive return true
                if month is Jan, Mar, May, July, Aug, Oct, Dec 
                   then if day is between 1 and 31 inclusive return true
                if month is Apr, June, Sept, Nov
                   then if day is between 1 and 30 inclusive return true
                if month is Feb
                   then determine if leap year by running function 
                   leapYear provided for us.
                   if leap year is true 
                   then if day is between 1 and 29, inclusive return true
                   if not leap year then if day is between 1 and 28, 
                   inclusive then return true
            end isDateValid
        if isDateValid is true then 
        Calculate
            if the month times the year is equal to the year modulus 100
            then output it is a magic date
            if it does not equal the year in 2 digit form
            then output that it is not a magic date    
        else output error message

        Output Program ID
    end main

    The output needs to include the books data of 6/10/1960 */
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool leapYear(int);
bool isDateValid(int, int, int);

int main()
{
    int month, day, year;

    cout << "Is the date you are thinking of a magic one? Let's see...\n";
    cout << "What is the month in numeric form only? "; cin >> month;
    cout << "What is the day of the month? "; cin >> day;
    cout << "What is the four digit year? "; cin >> year;

if (isDateValid(month, day, year) == false)
{
    cout << "The date you entered, "<< month << "/" << day << "/" << 
         year << " is NOT a VALID Date.\n";
    cout << "If you think I am wrong, please feel free to run me again";
}

else  if (month * day == year % 100) // if true then do this
{
    cout << "The date you entered, " << 
         month << "/" << day << "/" << year << " is a magic date!!\n"; 
}
else // if false then do this
{
    cout << "The date you entered, " << month << "/" << day << "/" <<
         year << " is NOT a magic date!!\n";
}

                                                            //Program ID
cout <<"\n" << "L5P1LB.cpp\n" << "11-26-12\n" << endl;
system ("pause");
return 0;
} //end main

// isDateValid function to validate date entered
bool isDateValid(int month, int day, int year)
{
    bool validation = true;  // validation set to true
    // if it is not between 1600 and 2100 then set to false
    if(!(year >= 1600 && year <=2100))
        validation = false;
    // call leapYear function
    if(leapYear(year))
{
    // if February and day is greater than 29 then set to false
    if ((month == 2) && (day > 29))
         validation = false;
}
    // else if NOT leapYear
    else if(!leapYear(year))
{
    // if February and day is greater then 28 then set to false
    if ((month == 2) && (day > 28))
          validation = false;
}    
    // if month is less then 1 and over 12 then set to false
    if((month < 1 && month > 12))
          validation = false;
    // if day is less then 1 then set to false    
    if(day < 1)    
          validation = false;
    // if month is 1 (Jan), 3 (Mar), 5 (May), 7 (July), 8 (Aug), 10 (Oct),
    // or 12 (Dec) and day is greater then 31 set to false    
    if((month == 1) || (month ==3) || (month == 5) || (month == 7) ||
         (month == 8) || (month == 10) || (month == 12) && (day > 31))
         validation = false;
    // if month is 4 (Apr), 6 (June), 9 (Sept), or 11 (Nov) and day is 
    // greater then 30 set to false
    if (((month == 4) || (month == 6) || (month == 9) || (month == 11)) && 
         (day > 30))
         validation = false;
    // else everything that is left set validation to true
    else
         validation = true;
return validation;
}  // End isDateValid

// leapYear function to determine if the year is a leap year for validation
bool leapYear(int year)
{
    return(year % 100 != 0 && year % 4 == 0) || (year % 400 == 0);
} // end leapYear
```

Sorry if I put in the wrong spot or anything!

Thanks for your help also.  It is truly appreciated.

Comment: Can you fix the indentation of your code? it's pretty hard to read

Comment: One obvious thing popping out is statement `validation == true;` is having `==` instead of `=`.

Comment: This isn't the bug, but on this line: `validation == true;` you probably mean `validation = true;` However, you should probably remove that and the `else` above it, or you're going to always be setting validation to true if that final test (number of days in month) passes. To find the actual bug, I'd suggest commenting out each of the validation steps one at a time to see which one is causing the problem.

Comment: What @whamma says last in the comment, or use a debugger to step through the function line by line while checking all conditions manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had a few mistakes in your date validation.

The operator precedence noted by Luchian is one, but you had a few others:

- You test that `month < 1 && month > 12` - this is impossible, a month cannot be smaller than 1 and greater than 12
- `validation == true` doesn't do anything. `==` is a comparison operator. Luckily this didn't affect your function as `validation` was already `true` when reaching this code.

I took the liberty to rewrite it in what I think is a cleaner fashion, but you could probably just fix the `month` check if you prefer to keep your version

```
bool isDateValid(int month, int day, int year)
{
    bool validation = true;
    if(!(year >= 1600 && year <=2100))
        validation = false;    

    if(day < 1)
        validation = false;

    switch(month)
    {
    case 2:
        if(leapYear(year)) // We only care about leap years in February 
            if(day > 29)
                validation = false;
        else
            if(day > 28)
                validation = false;
        break;
    case 1: case 3: case 5: case 7: case 8: case 10: case 12:
        if(day > 31)
            validation = false;
        break;
    case 4: case 6: case 9: case 11:
        if(day > 30)
            validation = false;
        break;
    default: // the month is not between 1 and 12
        validation = false;
        break;
    }
    return validation;
}
```

Comment: Actually my teacher ended up coming to the same conclusion as I just saw your post now.  However I wanted to say a big THANK YOU for taking the time to clean it up for me.  I knew there was a cleaner way of writing what I was doing but I wasn't sure on how the best approach would be.  Though I won't use it for this assignment I really wanted you to know how much it helped me look at writing things better and that your effort was not in vain. I'm sure that sounds extremely corny but realize I do appreciate you taking your time to help me out as well as truly teaching me something.  Thanks!!

Comment: Glad to help! That's why this community is around!  Feel free to ask any question, and if the moderators don't like it you'll know pretty quickly :) If its simple questions, feel free to contact me directly

Answer (score 1):

`||` is short-circuiting, so `(month == 1) || (month ==3) || (month == 5) || (month == 7) ||
     (month == 8) || (month == 10) || (month == 12) && (day > 31)` evaluates to `true` if the first conditions are met. You need to add an extra set of parenthesis:

`((month == 1) || (month ==3) || (month == 5) || (month == 7) ||
     (month == 8) || (month == 10) || (month == 12)) && (day > 31)`

Same for the other months.

Also,

```
validation == true;
```

is a no-op, you probably meant `validation = true`.

Comment: +1 - though it's not being short-circuiting that's the problem... just the precedence of `&&` not being lower than `||`.  The `validation == true` thing should be removed given validation's initialised to true anyway, even if sticking to the structured programming approach.

Comment: First thank you so much for your help.  Okay so I rewrote the code to exclude the final else statement and took at the validation = true part and it seems that I am validation on everything except for anything to do with a month! Any additional suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd suggest something more direct and concise.  The `?` ternary operator can be a little confusing at first, but is very simple once clearly understood.  I think of it as a kind of "if-else" that can be embedded in expressions.

```
bool isDateValid(int month, int day, int year)
{
    return year >= 1600 && year<= 2100 &&
           month >= 1 && month <= 12 &&
           day >= 1 &&
           day <= (month == 2 ? (leapyear(year) ? 29 : 28) :
                   month == 9 || month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 11 ? 30 : 31);
                   // "30 days has September, April, June and November..."
}
```

It may be a little more readable if you use an enum for month constants:

```
enum Month { Jan = 1, Feb, Mar, Apr ... };
```

Aim being to actually code:

```
day <= (month == Feb ? ...
```